# awsのVPCとサブネットを設定する際に理解できないことがあります…

Tags: aws, network

現在ネットワークについて学習を行っている学生です。
書籍で学習した知識でawsを使ってアプリケーションを構築しようと思い、作業をしている中で
VPCの設定、サブネットの設定を行った際にわからないことがありました。

VPCを10.0.0.0/16で作成し、サブネットを10.1.0.0/24で作成しました。
これはVPCの設定で用意したネットワーク領域が10.0.0.0 ~ 65536個分まで(第4オクテットから？)で、
サブネットは10.1.0.0~10.1.0.256まで用意されている認識で問題ないのでしょうか？
もしこのサブネットで何かしらインスタンスを立ち上げようと思った場合10.1.0.0~10.1.0.256の範囲でIPアドレスを割り当てるイメージであっていますか？

もしIPが枯渇した、あるいは他にサブネットを分けたくなった場合は同じ様に10.2.0.0/24、10.3.0.0/24のような形で割り当てるで問題ないのでしょうか？

また、根本的に理解できていない可能性があるので大変恐縮なのですが、VPCを10.0.0.0/16で割り当てる理由は何なのでしょうか？
第一オクテットが10で始まっている理由が理解できていないです…
10ではじめなければいけない理由はなにかあるのでしょうか？

周りに質問できる人がいなく、確信をもって学習を進めたかったので質問させていただきました。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、ご回答いただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

> これはVPCの設定で用意したネットワーク領域が10.0.0.0 ~ 65536個分まで(第4オクテットから？)で、
>   サブネットは10.1.0.0~10.1.0.256まで用意されている認識で問題ないのでしょうか？

サブネットは 10.1.0.0~10.1.0.255 までです

> もしこのサブネットで何かしらインスタンスを立ち上げようと思った場合10.1.0.0~10.1.0.256の範囲でIPアドレスを割り当てるイメージであっていますか？

0, 255 はネットワークとブロードキャスト用で予約されていて
AWS ではさらに 1, 2, 3 も予約されてます
使えるのは 4 〜 254 の 251 個です

> もしIPが枯渇した、あるいは他にサブネットを分けたくなった場合は同じ様に10.2.0.0/24、10.3.0.0/24のような形で割り当てるで問題ないのでしょうか？

問題ないです

> VPCを10.0.0.0/16で割り当てる理由は何なのでしょうか？

プライベートアドレスで使える空間が http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html で決まってます

```
 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

これ以外を使う場合グローバルアドレスとかぶる可能性があるので使えなくはないですが
被った場合にどちらをみにいくかをルート選択しなければいけなくなります

10 を使ってる理由はよくわかりません
10 から始まるのは 24bit  10.*.*.* 使えるので 16bit でいいなら 172 から始まるのを使うべきです
強いていうなら 10 の方が覚えやすいので枯渇を考えなければ 10 でもいいかもしれないです

Comment: プライベートアドレスで使える空間がRFCで定義されているのを知らなかったので大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。
また、私の知識不足で大変申し訳無いのですが、「10 から始まるのは 24bit 10...* 使えるので 16bit でいいなら 172 から始まるのを使うべきです」とご指摘頂いた部分が理解できませんでした…10から始まると24bit利用でき、172だと16bit利用できるとはどういう事なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

> VPCを10.0.0.0/16で作成し、サブネットを10.1.0.0/24で作成しました。

サブネットがVPCの範囲を超えてますね。
VPCのアドレス範囲内で、サブネットを分割してください。

- VPC: 10.0.0.0/16   ... 10.0.0.0 ～ 10.0.255.255 まで

  - Subnet1: 10.0.0.0/24  ... 10.0.0.0 ～ 10.0.0.255 まで
  - Subnet2: 10.0.1.0/24  ... 10.0.1.0 ～ 10.0.1.255 まで
    ::
  - Subnet256 まで作成できる （実際には AWSのほうで制限されて 上限は 200個まで）

下図のように、VPCの箱の中に、サブネットが入ってて、サブネットの箱の中にサーバーがある感じです。

◆VPCイメージ図
[image: VPCイメージ図]

> VPCを10.0.0.0/16で割り当てる理由は何なのでしょうか？

アドレス範囲は自由に変えられますので設計次第です。
ただし、プライベートアドレス空間の使用が推奨されています。

- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (10/8 プレフィックス)
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (172.16/12 プレフィックス)
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 プレフィックス)

この辺の詳細はユーザーガイドを見てください。
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html

(余談) ネットワークの勉強をされているということなので、アドバイスさせていただくと、実際のネットワークと、AWS とでは 結構違う部分もありますので、ご注意ください。AWSのほうが より抽象度が高く簡単です。(そこがいいところなんですが)

個人的には DockerやKVM仮想環境でVyOSを使って作るほうが 実際のネットワークに近い感じがします。もし興味があれば 調べてみてください。